# MS Excel, counting instances of strings it 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have Column A with multiple instances of Chicken, Pig, Cow and Column B with multiple instances of Happy, Sad, Angry.
How could I create a chart like this:
[Picture of spreadsheet I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwzIR.png)?
I have tried a pivot table which is typically great but it doesn't count the instances like I want which is probably due my limited experience with pivot tables.
I has hoping for a built in feature since macros would take a lot of time.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1566586/pivot-table-add-multiple-columns-that-share-the-same-set-of-values-as-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a sample, you can try this method.

1. Select the **Range**- go to **Insert**- **From Table/Range**:
   [image]
2. Drag Fields to area as shown in the following picture:
   [image]